# How can I store estimates for one of the equations contained in SUR Estimation

Tags: stata

I need to compare two different estimation methods and see if there are statistically same or not. However one of my estimation methods is SUR (Seemingly Unrelated Regression). And, I estimated the my 11 different models using

```
sureg (Y1 trend X1 .... X106) (Y2 trend X1..... X181) ..... (Y11 trend X1 .... X 130)
```

Then I estimated single OLS model as shown in following

```
glm(Y1 trend X1 ...... X106)
```

Now I need to test if parameter estimates of X1 to X106 comming from **sureg** is equal to **glm** estimates of  same variables or not? I need to use Haussman specification test. I couldn't figure how can I store parameters estimates for specific equation in an SUR system estimation.

I couldn't find object should I add to `estimates store XXX` to subset a part of SUR estimates.

It's not easy to give a working example using my own crowded data, but let me present same problem using stata's auto data.

```
. sysuse auto (1978 automobile data)


. sureg (price mpg headroom) (trunk weight length) (gear_ratio turn headroom)

Seemingly unrelated regression
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Equation             Obs   Params         RMSE  "R-squared"      chi2  P>chi2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ price                 74        2      2576.37      0.2266      21.24 
0.0000 trunk                 74        2     2.912933      0.5299      82.93   0.0000 gear_ratio            74        2     .3307276      0.4674      65.12   0.0000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------- price        |
         mpg |  -258.2886   57.06953    -4.53   0.000    -370.1428   -146.4344
    headroom |  -419.4592   390.4048    -1.07   0.283    -1184.639    345.7201
       _cons |   12921.65   2025.737     6.38   0.000     8951.277    16892.02
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------- trunk        |
      weight |  -.0010525   .0013499    -0.78   0.436    -.0036983    .0015933
      length |   .1735274   .0471176     3.68   0.000     .0811785    .2658762
       _cons |   -15.6766   5.182878    -3.02   0.002    -25.83485   -5.518345
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------- gear_ratio   |
        turn |  -.0652416   .0097031    -6.72   0.000    -.0842594   -.0462238
    headroom |  -.0601831   .0505198    -1.19   0.234    -.1592001    .0388339
       _cons |   5.781748   .3507486    16.48   0.000     5.094293    6.469202
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. glm (price mpg headroom)

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -686.17715  

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =    74 Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     = 71
                                                  Scale parameter =    6912463 Deviance         =  490784895.4                   (1/df) Deviance =    6912463 Pearson          =  490784895.4                  (1/df) Pearson  =    6912463

Variance function: V(u) = 1                       [Gaussian] Link function    : g(u) = u                       [Identity]

                                                  AIC             =   18.62641 Log likelihood   = -686.1771533                   BIC             =   4.91e+08

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
       price | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -259.1057   58.42485    -4.43   0.000    -373.6163   -144.5951
    headroom |  -334.0215   399.5499    -0.84   0.403    -1117.125     449.082
       _cons |   12683.31   2074.497     6.11   0.000     8617.375    16749.25
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

as you see for the price model (glm) parameter estimate of mpg coef is -259.10 and parameter for same variable estimated in SUR system is -258.288

Now I wanted to test if parameter estimates of GLM and SUR methods are statistically equal or not.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then add more detail!

Comment: I believe that the short answer is that there isn't a Stata command for the test you want.

`suest` is useful for this sort of problem, but only supports a limited set of estimators. [Stata manual `suest`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rsuest.pdf) provides useful discussion.

Comment: You'll have to adapt `suest` yourself, or consider another approach. Depending on what you're after you could bootstrap a distribution for each estimate and compare those.

Comment: This sentence isn't clear: "I couldn't find object should I add to `estimates store XXX` to subset a part of SUR estimates." Since your MWE does not include `estimates store`